# Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},f(x)=4x(1-x),f_n(x)=f(f_{n-1}(x))\;\forall n\geq 1$ and $f_0(x)=x$. Find number of solutions to the equation $f_n(x)=x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, maxima-minima, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},f(x)=4x(1-x),f_n(x)=f(f_{n-1}(x))\;\forall n\geq 1$ and $f_0(x)=x$.

Find number of solutions to the equation $f_n(x)=x$.

**My Attempt**

I tried plotting graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=f(f(x))$ by focusing on the fact when $f(x)=0$ and when $f(x)=1$ because $f(f(x))=0$ at these points and also found the points when $f(f(x))=1$. So I got that $f(f(x))=x$ has $3$ solutions. Can there be a recursive solution or some other approach here because this way I am not able to get any pattern.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3655004/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3617430/42969

Comment: Go into Desmos, type in $f(x) = 4x(1-x)$, and Desmos will let you plot $f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))),$ etc. Then add $y=x$ and look at the intersections; you should see a pattern appear immediately after looking at two or three levels.